# Like Pattern in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Display the details of those stores, which have `Bike` in their name.??

I am able to match substring using `%bike%` but how to match and retrieve data having `bike` anywhere in the `Name`?

Comment: like %bike% search in all content of your field

Comment: LIKE '%bike%' does return data having bike anywhere in the Name. If you expect other results, post sample data.

Comment: Bikes and Motorbikes... Its matching only 1 entry

Comment: There are many records with Bike in their Name and database I have used is Adventure works

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the problem with your query may be the default collation you are using.  You can also use `lower()`:

```
where lower(field_name) like '%bike%'
```

Answer (score 2):

You Can Retrieve data having that word by using the CHARINDEX Function as below:

```
SELECT Field_Name From TBL_Name WHERE CHARINDEX('Bike', Field_Name)>0
```

Comment: Why does this work where like '%bike%' doesn't? Appart from the collation effects, that is.